# How to remove return key when printing

Tags: assembly, output, edit, nasm, enter

I am trying to get the users name and display it with a greeting, how can I remove the return key as it displays the greeting on the next line?

Output is like this:

```
Hello!
Name
How are you?
```

I need it to be:

```
Hello! Name How are you?
```

.

```
    lea dx, [ANSNAME] ;get the name
    mov ah, 0Ah 
    int 21h

    mov byte [ANSNAME], 19h ; initialize name 25 chars max

    call CLRSCR

    lea dx, [GREET]
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    lea dx, [ANSNAME+2]
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    lea dx, [GREET2]
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    SECTION .data

   nextline db 0dh, 0ah, "$"
   ANSNAME times 25 db "$",0dh, 0ah,"$"
   GREET db "Hello!",0dh,0ah,"$"
   GREET2 db "How are you?",0dh,0ah,"$"
```

Comment: i removed it on the ANSNAME, it did not work, it did not display the name

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to write the max value **before** calling the DOS service!

   ```
   lea dx, [ANSNAME] ;get the name
   mov byte [ANSNAME], 19h ; initialize name 25 chars max
   mov ah, 0Ah 
   int 21h
   ```
2. Setup the input buffer without the carriage return and linefeed codes.

   ```
   ANSNAME times 2+25 db "$"
   ```
3. Remove the carriage return and linefeed codes from the *GREET* message and add a space after the text.

   ```
   GREET db "Hello! ", "$"
   ```
4. Add a space before the *GREET2* message.

   ```
   GREET2 db " How are you?",0dh,0ah,"$"
   ```
5. Before you can print the name you have to remove the carriage return (0dh) that DOS appended to the result.

   ```
   mov bl, [ANSNAME+1]
   mov bh, 0
   mov byte [ANSNAME+2+bx], "$"
   lea dx, [ANSNAME+2]
   mov ah, 09h
   int 21h
   ```

Comment: I might be inclined to add a `0ah` to the beginning _GREET_ if the intention of the OP is to not overwrite the line where the name was entered.

Comment: The OP clears the screen through `call CLRSCR`. It would not make a difference.

Comment: Ah good point, I scanned the code quickly and forgot he cleared the screen through a function not declared in the code.

Comment: Thanks for the contributions, I get this error though on: mov byte ptr [ANSNAME+2+bx], "$", it says comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand, Illegal command

Comment: @JedrekFadul I've edited Fifoernik's answer to conform to NASM syntax.

Answer (score -1):

Nope. The only reason why it's in three lines is because for each line you keep adding '0dh, 0ah', which is equivalent to a '\n' in C. Remove those and it should look fine.

Comment: It is a little more complex than removing just `0dh` and `0ah` since you must remove the carriage return off of the end of the name when it is placed in the input buffer which the other answer also deals with. There is also a bug with setting up the length in the return buffer.